# Current Version of HSQLDB in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-base

I was hoping to develop a small database/form application for a client, but it would require some functionality to at least auto-populate fields, but probably also trigger insertions of calculated rows into another table.  I did a little homework on this and it looks like the database in LibreOffice is HyperSQLDB and the version presently embedded doesn't support triggers.  Is that still true?  If so, is upgrading it a hassle?

Thanks,

-Todd

Comment: Current version of HSQLDB is 1.8.  It works fine for many things.  This doc list I put together might be of some help to you:  https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/80972/to-learn-libreoffice-base-are-there-introductions-or-tutorials/   There you will find a link to the 1.8 and 2.3 reference manuals, and lots of other useful links.

Answer (score 0):

The included (i.e. embedded) version is still old - 1.8.0.10 for LO 5.2.3.3.

However it does not matter, because you should [never use an embedded setup](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/FAQ_(Base)#So_why_should_I_avoid_.27embedded_databases.27.3F) except for testing.  Otherwise it will crash about once every 5 minutes.

Instead, use a split database setup, either the latest version of HSQLDB or another database such as MySQL.  First install the database, and then create an LO Base file and "connect to an existing database."

See also https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=55220.